# UISearchDisplayController inside popover - bad animation on cancelling search

Tags: ios, ipad, uisearchbar, uipopovercontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

My iPad app uses a popover to perform some searching. The search results are handled using a UISearchDisplayController, and I am having some trouble removing some little graphical artefacts.

My popover starts out looking like this:

[image: UISearchBar inside popover]

When you click inside the search bar, the popover expands (animated) to:
[image: UISearchBar & expanded table view]

All good so far... typing in the search field overlays a new table view showing the results of your search term.

But if you don't type anything into the search field, the overlay stays translucent, as above. The problem then comes when you click the cancel button next to the search field. A visual artefact appears at the bottom of the table view: an area the same height as one of the table view cells goes completely clear immediately, while the rest of the overlay animates to 0 alpha. The screenshot below is as close to the start of the animation I could get:

[image: Disabling search field]

The popover also resizes to the original size in my case, although the artefact remains even if there is no resizing.

Given that all the important functionality of the search is handled by the UISearchDisplayController, I'm not sure what to change to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug [worth reporting](http://bugreport.apple.com). There are actually a surprising number of bugs in UIPopoverController. At least 3 that I know about separate from this, none of which are planned to be fixed anytime soon (I asked several engineers at WWDC this year). One of my bugs was actually related to the UISearchDisplayController in a popover, specifically how it handles filter buttons if the Popover is in the detail view (it renders them in the worst possible way, on the same line as the text view and completely unusable).

Comment: Yes I have encountered the scope bar issue also, and as much as I would like to include one in my own search interface, I don't really have time to implement a convincing substitute of my own.

Comment: I think this question has been up long enough that I should submit a bug report as you suggest - I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give you better news. If it's any help, I'm partway through reimplementing PopoverController. It probably won't be quite as pretty as Apples, but I already have the search and filter bar working correctly (haven't made it to the results table and shadowbox yet). If you check back on my blog it'll be posted there when complete, under an MIT license.